# EF Core 5 - executing stored procedure using FromSqlRaw results in "An items with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Pulling my hair out on this one. I am executing SQL Server stored procedures using `FromSqlRaw` in various places of my code and all its working... except one.

This is the structure of the data returned from that stored procedure:

```
[site_no] [missing_date] [missing_reason] [area_no]
```

I have a class for this data:

```
public class MissingData
{
    public short site_no { get; set; }
    public DateTime missing_date { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    public string missing_reason { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int area_no { get; set; }
}
```

In my context I have this.

```
public DbSet<MissingData> MissingData { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MissingData>().HasNoKey();
}
```

and the code to execute it all is this

```
var dbSet = connection.Set<MissingData>();
var items = dbSet.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList(); // SQL is string with query
```

I get an exception on the last line of code:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: site_no

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

In regards to primary keys of the table. Both site_no and area_no are primary keys of their respected tables. The SQL does a join from 2 tables. So I did try this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MissingData>().HasKey(x => new {x.site_no, x.area_no});
```

This made no difference. I have even edited the stored procedure to create a temporary table with no primary keys. Fill the table and then return this table. Still the same error.

Exception Stack trace, no inner exceptions

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException[T](T key)
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList`1 columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

An example of data returned

```
[site_no] [missing_date] [missing_reason] [area_no]  
[56]    [2021-06-10 00:00:00]   [FTP From Site Failed]  [53]  
[56]    [2021-06-10 00:00:00]   [FTP From Site Failed]  [58]  
[56]    [2021-06-10 00:00:00]   [FTP From Site Failed]  [3]  
[56]    [2021-06-10 00:00:00]   [FTP From Site Failed]  [55]  
[9] [2021-06-10 00:00:00]   [FTP From Site Failed]  [11]
```

Comment: That error reads to me like you have already used that primary key, just because your model has the property "HasNoKey" doesn't mean the database does.  Could you provide the sql?

Comment: Difficult because its all business so confidential. However, see my update.

Comment: Can you specify the exception and inner exception type?

Comment: @vernou will update with exception stack trace, no inner exception.

Comment: If is read only, maybe you can try with `dbSet.FromSqlRaw(sql).AsNoTracking().ToList()`.

Comment: @vernou just tried, still the same. To eliminate the key, is there a way of stripping it out of the return data? As I say in my update, I created a temp table without the key and still don't work.

Comment: In your query, just create a "key" using the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function then use the `Key` attribute in your model.

Comment: Can you check if `OnModelCreating` is called?

Comment: @vernou just checked and it is being called. Something I am missing here because I have just edited the SQL to ignore column 'site_no'. So this column does not return. Error is still there!!

Comment: To add, I just renamed the c# property to 'SiteNo' and set to NotMapped. So I changed the name, set it to no mapped and I am not returning the column from SQL. Error is still there and still referring to 'site_no' lol

Comment: It's sound like the stored procedure return 2 columns "site_no".

Comment: @vernou well this is in embarrassing. I was replying to this and then it hit me. There are 6 databases and all the Stored Procedures are duplicated for each database. Been working on one database and switched over, in code, to another. Basically I been editing the wrong database! and not applying my changes to all of them. Who set these up!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace, I think the error is throw by EF Core from :

[GitHub source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/b0a3186efa2486b51d7b81e3c90744bc477027e3/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal/FromSqlQueryingEnumerable.cs#L134) :

```
public static int[] BuildIndexMap(IReadOnlyList<string> columnNames, DbDataReader dataReader)
{
    var readerColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, dataReader.FieldCount)
        .ToDictionary(dataReader.GetName, i => i, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    ...
```

The error isn't about a duplicate row, but a duplicate column name. Maybe you stored procedure return two (or more) column with the name "site_no".